# Compare two lists in Pandas Dataframe with different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes with lists which I need to compare in order to know if one row is the same than the other and then add it.

The two datasets are:

**Dataset 1**

```
sex     age     zip_code    
0   F   46  08204   [6, 40, 9, 44, 30]
1   F   40  08205   [33, 41, 48, 50, 30]
2   F   46  08206   [32, 33, 4, 37, 43, 21]
3   F   60  08304   [37, 39, 7, 42, 11, 49]
4   M   24  08507   [32, 15, 23, 25, 29]
5   M   42  08917   [9, 42, 41, 13, 45, 23]
6   F   50  08921   [10, 50, 29, 52]
7   F   37  10627   [41, 3, 29, 39]
```

**Dataset 2**

```
user_id           weeks                      blood_levels
0   1101    [15, 23, 25, 29, 32]    [126, 127, 120, 111, 107]
1   1122    [33, 41, 48, 50, 30]    [70, 72, 69, 68, 74, 76, 72]
2   2112    [4, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 24, 31, 33, 36]     [117, 96, 114, 99, 119, 100, 93, 87, 80, 74]
3   2200    [3, 5, 7, 14, 21, 22, 27, 28, 34]   [152, 126, 165, 169, 167, 169, 140, 154, 157]
```

What I am trying to compare is that the list of the column "weeks" from dataset2 are in the list of of the column "weeks" from dataset 1 (All of them). If this is true,the "user_id" and "blood_levels" columns from dataset 2 should be added to Dataset 1. Thus, **expected output:**

```
sex     age     zip_code    weeks          user_id      blood_levels
0   F   46  08204   [6, 40, 9, 44, 30]       1101         [126, 127, 120, 111, 107]
1   F   40  08205   [33, 41, 48, 50, 30]     1122         [70, 72, 69, 68, 74, 76, 72]
2   F   46  08206   [32, 33, 4, 37, 43, 21]
3   F   60  08304   [37, 39, 7, 42, 11, 49]
4   M   24  08507   [32, 15, 23, 25, 29]
5   M   42  08917   [9, 42, 41, 13, 45, 23]
6   F   50  08921   [10, 50, 29, 52]
7   F   37  10627   [41, 3, 29, 39]
```

Note that not all the weeks from dataset 2 are in dataset 1.
What I have tried so far is:

```
df_1['intersection'] = [list(set(a).intersection(set(b))) for a, b in zip(df_one.weeks, df_two.weeks)]
```

However it gives an error of different length.

**Added sample data:**

```
df1 = {'sex': {0: 'F', 1: 'F', 2: 'F', 3: 'F', 4: 'M'},
 'age': {0: 46, 1: 40, 2: 46, 3: 60, 4: 24},
 'zip_code': {0: '08204', 1: '08205', 2: '08206', 3: '08304', 4: '08507'},
 'weeks': {0: [6, 40, 9, 44, 30],
  1: [33, 41, 48, 50, 30],
  2: [1, 2, 6, 10, 13, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29],
  3: [4, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 24, 31, 33, 36],
  4: [32, 15, 23, 25, 29]}}

df2 = {'user_id': {0: 1101, 1: 1122, 2: 2112, 3: 2200, 4: 3010},
 'weeks': {0: [15, 23, 25, 29, 32],
  1: [8, 9, 12, 20, 25, 30, 35],
  2: [4, 10, 11, 16, 17, 18, 24, 31, 33, 36],
  3: [3, 5, 7, 14, 21, 22, 27, 28, 34],
  4: [1, 2, 6, 10, 13, 19, 25, 26, 27, 29]},
 'blood_levels': {0: [126, 127, 120, 111, 107],
  1: [70, 72, 69, 68, 74, 76, 72],
  2: [117, 96, 114, 99, 119, 100, 93, 87, 80, 74],
  3: [152, 126, 165, 169, 167, 169, 140, 154, 157],
  4: [99, 82, 74, 69, 91, 96, 96, 68, 78, 89]}}
```

Can you help me to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: You need merge both DataFrames first, is it possible? Is there some column for merge like `user_id` in `df1` ?

Comment: No, there isn't "user_id" in df1. The only common column in both is the "weeks" columns

Comment: So first merge DataFrames by `weeks` like `df = df1.merge(df2, on='weeks')` and of correct joined then use your solution with change `df_one.days, df_two.days` to `df['days1'].dt.days, df['days2'].dt.days`

Comment: When trying to do merge, as weeks is a list, it's giving me `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`.

Comment: So need explode first `df1 = df1.explode('weeks')` same for `df2`

Comment: But still this is only guessing, is possible create data sample with also columns for weeks in dictionaries like `df1.head(10).to_dict())` ? Same for `df2` with expected ouput?

Comment: I've added sample data and the expected output. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I cannot find weeks, you forget for them?

Comment: It should be fine now. Sorry

Comment: So you need join both DataFrames by weeks?

Comment: How is it possible? Is possible see how looks data after join?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230248/discussion-between-js352-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion solution is:

```
#cross join
df = df1.assign(a=1).merge(df2.assign(a=1), on='a')
#columns to sets
df['weeks_x'] = df['weeks_x'].apply(set)
df['weeks_y'] = df['weeks_y'].apply(set)

#compared columns
df = df[df['weeks_x'].eq(df['weeks_x'])]

#intersection
df['intersection']=[list((a).intersection(b)) for a, b in zip(df['weeks_x'], df['weeks_y'])]
```